# How does perlin noise work?

Tags: algorithms

I would like to write a function that returns a 2D array of floating point numbers representing pixels in an image. I have tried implementing perlin noise 3 times and have followed this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ3bvCkHJtE&t=1008s) video. So far, I've been getting numbers larger than 1 as my final result. I've tried reading the wikipedia page on perlin noise, but they aren't written in English a normal person could understand. Could someone guide me through the perlin noise algorithm and provide an example, preferably in C (I also know C++, Python, Java and javascript). Thanks. (If you prefer simply fixing my existing code, I'd be happy to provide it, just let me know)

UPDATE:
I read the Wikipedia page on perlin noise (as Yuval Filmus recommended in the comments) and I have several questions:

What does randomGradient do and how does it work? Why aren't the numbers it returns truly random?

How are the grid cell coordinates calculated (why is there x0 and x1 + y0 and y1)?

What does (the) permutation (array) do? I have no clue what permutation is.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained description of your understanding of the approach you are currently taking?  Not code, but concise mathematics or pseudocode.

Comment: @D.W. I understand exactly what the guy explains in the video, except for the part regarding bilinear interpolation. He added à formula with the variable FracX and another with FracY and I don’t know what they represent. You can refer to the video, but I will also add pseudocode tomorrow as it’s quite late where I live :) (thanks a lot for actually taking the time to respond to this question!!!)

Comment: We'd like questions to be self-contained, so people don't have to visit an external link to answer the question. It helps to make your question useful for others by providing background. Showing us your understanding might also help us get a sense of your current level of understanding how we might best be able to help.

Comment: Once you've reworded the question to be a bit more self-contained, this question might be more appropriate for [computergraphics.SE]. Don't forget to check their guidelines before posting.

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I just read the wikipedia page, and I dont understand how I'm supposed to pick the random gradient, and how the distance vectors (from the gradietns to the cell) should be calculated

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I also don't understand what the randomGradient function does in the wikipedia implementation (and how it works)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus plus, what does (the) permutation do?

Comment: @D.W. updated the question

Comment: @Pseudonym I've added to the question in order to make it more specific

Comment: Have you checked the implementation on Wikipedia? It has code for randomGradient.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, that’s exactly what I don’t understand, the implementation

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT:" or "UPDATE:" -- see https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  We prefer that you edit the question to include information, not put it in comments.  Please make the question read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you are hoping for, for "What does randomGradient do?" - it is some code; and it has a comment "Create random direction vector".